# Difficulties with the % Operator in Python

Tags: python, operator-keyword

```
myvar = "How are you ?"    
print("%s %s") % (hello, myvar)
```

Its one of my python Task for University but it doesnt work ??
I use Python 3 could it be for 2 ??
And how would it look like for 3 then ?

Comment: Have you tried looking through the documentation for string formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move it inside brackets

```
print("%s %s" % (hello, myvar))
```

as in your case "%" is used in the context "NoneType tuple", while it should be used in a context "str tuple"

Comment: Thank you can i recommand you somehow ??

Comment: Somewhere you can accept this answer (I don't know where, I never posted a question).

Comment: Click on the "check" nxt to the upvote counter

Answer (score -1):

In python3, the **print** is a function unlike in python 2 where it is actually a statement.

so, as it is told, in python3 give the argument inside () ie

```
print(hello, myvar)
```